# Why am I getting iso 8601 dates from my Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, date, google-sheets

I'm using [Seekwell](https://www.seekwell.io/) to connect my AWS postgres database to Sheets.

I think I'm converting my dates to standard 'date' (`YYYY-MM-DD`) format in the code, eg.

`date(date_trunc('day', u.created_at::date)) Date_Created`

However, when the query is run, my dates are iso 8601, eg.

`2018-05-16T00:00:00.000Z`

Of course, given that my results are going into Google Sheets, I can always convert those dates there in sheets, but that adds a layer of complexity that is hard to manage.

How can I make sure the dates are formatted correctly before the results land in sheets?

Answer (score 3):

Michael from Seekwell tells me this is:

> a bit of bug with how JDBC handles dates in the background. You're on Postgres, right? This should work from within the add-on:

`to_char(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

> Sheets will recognize that result as a date.

This worked.

Comment: I was going to ask you what Google Sheets expects.  If it can accept a _text_ date in the format you want, then you really want _text_, not date, output.  What you wrote above is precisely that.